How to do a prove where $\cos(4x)\cos(2x)\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(8x)}{8\sin(x)}$?
I was doing some trigonometry proves when I came across the one in the attached image 1. I've been stuck on this question for quite some time. Does anyone know the prove to the question above since I do not have the answers for this question?
Prove the identity:
$$\cos(4x)\cos(2x)\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(8x)}{8\sin(x)}$$

In general, $$\cos(x)\cos (2x)\cos(4x)\dots \cos(2^{n-1}x)= \frac{\sin(2^nx)}{2^n\sin(x)}$$ You can find this here at MSE.

Hint: Use the identity $cos(a).cos(2a).cos(4a)....cos(2^{n-1}a)=\frac{sin(2^na)}{2^nsina}$

We use the identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$.
\begin{align*}
 \cos x\cos(2x)\cos(4x)
 & = \frac{\sin x\cos x\cos(2x)\cos(4x)}{\sin x} \\
 & = \frac{\sin(2x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)}{2\sin x} \\
 & = \frac{\sin(4x)\cos(4x)}{4\sin x} \\
 & = \frac{\sin(8x)}{8\sin x}.
\end{align*}
